# put the word "Please Wait, Don't Close The Windows" on Ajax Loading

Tags: css, ajax, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I am using partial view for my projects.
My Ajax Code is Here :

```
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var dhnFiles = $("#fileDHN")[0].files;

        if (dhnFiles.length == 0) {
          alert("Pilih file DHN terlebih dahulu!");
          return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < dhnFiles.length; i++) {
            formData.append("DataDHN", dhnFiles[i]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("PartialViewTableDataDHN")",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#TableDHN").html(data);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Error submitting data to server.");
        });
    });
```

The loading about 20minutes. and I want the user wait and don't close the windows.
How do i add the words 'Please wait, don't close the windows' while loading.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can perhaps add a overlay `div` which you can show using the `beforeSend` pre-request callbak... then you can hide the ovelay message when ajax is completed...

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("PartialViewTableDataDHN")",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        $('#overlay_message').show();
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    $("#TableDHN").html(data);
}).fail(function () {
    alert("Error submitting data to server.");
}).completed(function(){
    $('#overlay_message').hide();
});
```

See how to create an overlay: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp